# Atualizar tabela usando PDO com 2 foreachs

Tags: php, array, pdo, foreach

Olá,

```
public function update($idsimages, $dir_images)
{
try {

   $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE images SET
   dir_images = :dir_images
   WHERE id_images = :id_images");


foreach ($idsimages as $idsimage) { 


     foreach ($dir_images as $item){

        $stmt->bindParam(":id_images", $idsimage);
        $stmt->bindParam(":dir_images", $item); 

     } //end foreach dir_images 

    $stmt->execute();

} // end foreach idsimages


   return true;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); 
  return false;
 }
}
```

As variveis `$idsimages` (contem os ids que serão atualizados) e `$dir_images` (contem as urls) são arrays, os dois arrays possuem a mesma quantidade de chaves

Acontece que não esta fazendo o updade, coloquei echo nas duas variaveis e depois do submit imprime repetidamente, varias vezes, as imagens e os ids.

tentei mudar varias vezes os foreachs e tambem inserir if isset para não repetir, mas não consegui

PRINTS

**print_r ($idsimages);**

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 )
```

**print_r ($dir_images);**

```
Array ( [0] => uploads/images/image5.jpg [1] => uploads/images/image6.jpg [2] => uploads/images/image7.jpg [3] => uploads/images/image8.jpg)
```

Se inserir echo na função:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":id_images", $idsimage);
echo $idsimage;
$stmt->bindParam(":dir_images", $item); 
echo $item;
```

retorna:

```
5 image5.PNG 5 image6.jpg 5 image6.jpg 5  image6.jpg
6 image5.PNG 6 image6.jpg 6 image6.jpg 6 image6.jpg
7 image5.PNG 7 image6.jpg 7 image6.jpg 7 image6.jpg
8 image5.PNG 8 image6.jpg 8 image6.jpg 8 image6.jpg
```

Comment: vc só faz o bind do ultimo elemento do foreach interno e executa a consulta N vezes com o mesmo valor. Se tem erro na consulta veja o retornor de `$stmt->errorInfo():`

Comment: Obrigada @rray alguma ideia de como resolver? A consulta não retorna nenhum erro mesmo com sua sugestão

Answer (score 0):

Parece melhor mudar a lógica, ou seja realizar o update dentro do foreach interno e não como descrito no comentário.

```
foreach ($idsimages as $idsimage) { 
   foreach ($dir_images as $item){
      if(!$stmt->execute(array(':id_images' => $idsimage, ':dir_images' => $item))){
         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
      }
    } //end foreach dir_images 
}
```

Comment: sem alteração no resultado, continua não salvando, sem erros também

Comment: @Gisele o autocommit está ligado ou não? depois do if adicione `$this->db->commit()` veja se grava a alteração.

Comment: sinceramente nem sabia que tinha isso no mysql, acabei de pesquisar estou tentando entender

Comment: @Gisele Se ele estiver desligado, a alteração seja um update/inserte ou delete so entra em vigor se existir um commit.

Comment: estou trabalhando com os arquivos diretamente da hospedagem hostgator (compartilhada), como faço para ver se esta ativado?

Comment: Com o `$this->db->commit()` depois do if não funcionou? talvez tenha dada um erro porém não foi exibido, coloca essas duas linhas no inicio do arquivo, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` @Gisele

Comment: Insert e select esta trabalhando normalmente, para exibir os erros já estava ativado, com o commit depois do if retorna `There is no active transaction`,

Comment: @Gisele se vc copiar e colocar essa consulta no banco(e substituir os valores claro) funciona?

Comment: sim, funcionou normal

Comment: @Gisele faz uma ultima coisa novamente esse arquivo para o host de produção.

Comment: mas ele já esta em produção, com acesso restrito

Comment: @Gisele não tem nenhuma indicação do que seja o erro.

Comment: Não sei, acho que a lógica esta errada mesmo, da pra usar `do while` nesse caso?

Comment: veja os os resultados (prints) das variaveis para o código da minha pergunta

Comment: @Gisele pq vc tem os dois foreachs?